# very slow file copying on same disk

Tags: files, copy

On Ubuntu 16.02 LTS the copying time for a 1 MB file between directories on the same disk starts at about 0.02 seconds and increases to over 10 seconds as the session progresses. I am mainly using my own Fortran programs and none of them show any specific problems.

Comment: I suspect its a fortran coding issue or compiler option and not Ubuntu related (*assuming a `cp` of the same files is quick*).  I'd suggest checking your code, then check compiler options (even the C code generated depending on compiler you are using).  *there was no february release in 2016, its 16.04 as it was in April*

Comment: In a separate terminal window, watch `journalctl --follow` as you do your copies. That will show all log messages, including disk failures. Also, do you have swap space defined?